# How to Execute Actions Email in Keycloak

Tags: curl, keycloak

I am trying to trigger sending email using Keycloak API, but not succeeding. As described in documentation first I am getting token for my admin user:

```
 curl \
  -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
  -d "username=admin" \
  -d "password=admin" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I am successfully getting a token, which I am then using in my second call as follows:

```
curl -v  -X PUT -d '["UPDATE_PASSWORD"]' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJqZEpWUW1QdEdsT3Azd0xYV2tWWVJ2ZzJXNkRubVBPSHNGQ0t5WGQ5RkVZIn0.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.qJJ1jMs4p8V2CbtKsaVyUhWwiQur7hAwyYi14RGx5T0on6EelRNlFtduGu0XOBeB2gZ8VwuVYgmb8SGXupvJs2LfqhXMnZIy0E7y4QX0ZJQ_YH8dzAZTU6x9cJlSmFY3tTts1CF7-ySDI-ZiaKST7eVT-lkxb5fNBj2_C-6-wwOtxmctSCrQZcdKzGxf0iAYTieaGgNTJf_e6FTusvHLzFyUCAjHszV5Gw-gkzlM7R3uE9wWxjPZgkFz5zGxgKrnijZn45r0CIDQb7kKxCalBvYb-saNscpelzyHqyEd1her90UoHcLyE0JexF37Qqz040JxeJt0I1nOOADAjO8X2Q" \
    "http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/local/users/4553/execute-actions-email"
```

Answer I am getting is 404.

I figured that the problem is I am using user from user federation with an id from my database. If I create user in keycloak and use id that keycloak generated it will work.The thing is I need this functionality for federated users.
Any hints?

Comment: Found the answer, had to implement methods of  UserQueryProvider interface.

Comment: I've exact requirement.. can you please suggest how to trigger reset password email for federated user using UserQueryProvider?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022. Keycloak 19.02 the Documentation States:
[image]

Which is in fact wrong. The right api endpoint is the one mentioned by gohar.gasparyan

Edit: Which is in fact me not reading since the Documentation states at the top

[image]

The UserQueryProvider can be found in Groups

[image]

I have a user that is part of that group, logs in using username/password ( I couldn't figure out setting an access token ) and then uses the API Endpoints using a Bearer Token.

Full Script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

KEYCLOAK_URL=http://localhost:8080/auth
KEYCLOAK_REALM=myRealmName
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=serviceAccount
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET=serviceAccountPassword
REDIRECT_URL=http://redirect-link-after-action.com
# Realm -> Manage -> Clients -> ClientID of connected application
CLIENT_ID=ConnectApplicationClientID

set -x

export TKN=$(curl -X POST "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
 -d "username=${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}" \
 -d "password=${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET}" \
 -d 'grant_type=password' \
 -d 'client_id=admin-cli' | jq -r '.access_token')

#curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/admin/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/users/${USER_ID}" \
RAW=$(curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/admin/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/users" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TKN" | jq .)

eval "$( echo $RAW | jq -r '@sh "values=( \([.[].id]) )"' )"

REDIRECT_URI_ENCODED=$(printf %s $REDIRECT_URL | jq -sRr @uri)


for i in "${values[@]}"; do
  curl -v -X PUT "${KEYCLOAK_URL}/admin/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/users/${i}/execute-actions-email?redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI_ENCODED}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TKN" -d '["UPDATE_PASSWORD"]'
done
```

Make sure to add the redirect_uri to the valid redirection urls in the client configuration

[image]

After all that endavour we end with the nice Link "Back to Application"

[image]

Take note that your email account update links will refer the KEYCLOAK_URL variable unless you specify a Frontend URL in the Realm -> Configure -> Realm settings

[image]