# Keycloak itegrate Registration access key / password

Tags: keycloak

I want to ask if somebody tried to gate the keycloak registration behind a password.

I want the registration to be open in a sense where you first enter a pre-shared token to be then allowed to register.

This is just to make it simpler to add users, an alternative i can think of is batch process emails and just add accounts via api and then send a reset credential action like here: [How to Execute Actions Email in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041506/how-to-execute-actions-email-in-keycloak/73970963#73970963)

Did someone try something like the password to continue to registration?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in details? Its very vague

Comment: The use-case I imagine has a password field to fill out. Upon success you get authorized and redirected to the registration page.